# VBA coding using last used column number

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write VBA code to sum up cells, in the process i calculate the latest updated column using the statement:

```
clncnt1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("XFD16").End(-4159).Column
```

Suppose I capture the `clncnt1` as 20 which is column P. Now how do I use:

```
wb.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(16, clncnt).Formula = "=sum(*P12:P13*)"
```

using the column number `clncnt1` that I just captured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked wb.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(11, clncnt + 3).Formula = "=sum(" & _ wb.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(8, clncnt + 3).Address & ":" & _ wb.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(9, clncnt + 3).Address & ")"

Answer (score 1):

replace your sum with below

```
"=sum(" & Cells(12, clncnt1 ).Address & ":" & Cells(13, clncnt1 ).Address & ")"
```

you are actually getting the addresses of the range and then concatenating it all together. 
Full code:

```
clncnt1 = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("XFD16").End(-4159).Column
Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(16, clncnt1).Formula = "=sum(" & Cells(12, clncnt1).Address & ":" & Cells(13, clncnt1).Address & ")"
```

Comment: Thanks,I am sorry for not mentioning that I was using VBA in powerpoint. And I have used the cells function as you mentioned. I come across  Run-time error '1004', Methods cells object _global failed. Can you kindly suggest the solution ?

Comment: this worked wb.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(11, clncnt + 3).Formula = "=sum(" & _
            wb.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(8, clncnt + 3).Address & ":" & _
            wb.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(9, clncnt + 3).Address & ")"

Comment: ahh yes cells would only work in excel, wb.Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(12, clncnt1 ).Address & ":" & wb.Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(13, clncnt1 ).Address would have probably worked too as you are telling code this workbook on this worksheet. Could you mark this as the answer if this has helped you continue. little grey tick the left of the answer